# Add a string to every line of a selection

Tags: notepad++

To prepend a string to every line of a selection, I usually use the "increase line indent" (which adds a tab to every line) and then run a search for tab / replace with my string.

Does anyone know how to append a string to every line of a selection?

Comment: One method of doing the prepend that doesn't involve find/replace is to move your cursor to the start of the first line, hold down `Alt + Shift` and use the cursor down key to extend the selection to the end of the block. This allows you to type on every line simultaneously

Comment: I've undeleted my answer below

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Note: I misread the question initially, so I've posted this as a comment instead as it's still potentially useful but not an answer**

One method that doesn't involve find/replace (but only works if you want to do it on *every* line, including blank lines in your block), is this:

- Move your cursor to the start of the first line
- Hold down `Alt + Shift` and use the cursor down key to extend the selection to the end of the block

This allows you to type on every line simultaneously

Comment: Thanks, did not find an answer to my specific question but this solved my problem / very useful.

Comment: @Simon Simply superb

Comment: At least in my current Notepad++ version (7.7.1) this only works if the lines have the same length, otherwise it will insert on every line at the same column as the length of the first line of the selection.

Answer (score 7):

1. Choose *Search* -> *Find*
2. Select the *Replace* tab
3. Choose *Regular expression* as *Search Mode* in the bottom left
4. Enter as *Find what:* **$**
5. Enter as *Replace with:* **the string you want to have at the end of the lines**
6. Check *In selection*
7. Click *Find Next* or *Replace All*

This site is nice for testing regular expressions and has a quick reference:

http://rubular.com/

Comment: But ^ is start of line, guess you mean $? But anyway, both gives me "The regular expression to search is formed badly"

Comment: Still gives me "The regular expression to search is formed badly", im using Notepad++ v.5.6.4 (unicode)

Comment: Yes, I read your question wrong first, but then I updated my answer. Don't know what it is, then. I have Notepad++ 5.9.3 on Windows 7. Maybe you can try upgrading, in case this error is specific to your version of Notepad++?

Also maybe you can try to search for regular expression "a" or "." to see if it is regular expressions in general that don't work in your setup.

Answer (score 5):

Replace the regular expression `$` with the string you want.

Comment: it gives me "The regular expression to search is formed badly", how should I format the $?

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively,

1. Choose *Search -> Replace*
2. Choose *Extended* for *Search Mode*
3. *Find what:* **\n**
4. *Replace with:* **Whatever\n**

Note that if you leave off the \n in the *Replace with*, all your lines will be pasted together (which is probably not what you want).

I usually leave Notepad++ in Extended mode because it allows me to optionally paste lines to gether (by removing \n) or split them (by inserting \n), and doesn't get confused by special characters like *+() etc.  (Which I am often searching for in C++ code.)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using notepad++.
Its explained here step by step.
http://dotnet-programming-solutions.blogspot.ae/2012/11/how-to-add-text-to-beginning-or-end-of.html
Basically its a regular expression match and replace. It is so simple as find->replace all.

Comment: This adds nothing that has not already been said.

Answer (score 0):

ABOUT selected lines,i have a trick
1.first,learn to how insert every line at start and line.(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SiPLZzRqEwM)
2.cut the text(you want to do),paste these a new file (in notepad)
3.insert(according to 1)
4.cut these and paste to your origin file

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: if you try do these ,it will work.